# Delete rows in all tables matched by CREATED_BY column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-delete, delete-row

I have CREATED_BY column in all my tables of database. I want to delete rows across all tables marched by CREATED_BY='xyz' column value. Instead of writing individual DELETE query, is there a simple way to achieve this oracle database.

Comment: Write a procedure to fetch all table names  create by you and then delete from each table, the rows that are created by 'xyz'

Comment: instead of stored procedure, is there some tool like SQL Developer where I can achieve this?

Comment: @user1614862 No tool is that much customized  to achieve your requirement. A procedure is a good idea. See below how you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Procedure` like below. This would take in the `'xyz'` as input and delete all the rows from all the table having `created_by = 'xyz'`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE del_row (usrnm VARCHAR2)
AS
   TYPE var IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (100)
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   v_var   var;

   v_sql   VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   SELECT tname
     BULK COLLECT INTO v_var
     FROM col
    WHERE cname = 'CREATED_BY';

   FOR i IN 1 .. v_var.COUNT
   LOOP
      v_sql := 'Delete from  ' || v_var (i) || ' where CREATED_BY like ''%'||usrnm||'%''';          
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql  ;
   END LOOP;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

Demo:

```
CREATE  TABLE testt
(
   col1         VARCHAR2 (1),
   created_by   VARCHAR2 (3)
);


SQL> SELECT * FROM testt;

C CRE
- ---
A XYZ
B XYZ

SQL> EXEC del_row('XYZ');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM testt;

no rows selected
```

Comment: can I have "like" instead of = in the delete query, actually created_by column will have values starting with xyz but will have different value at the end something like this "xyz_anyString", I want o use wild card for anyString like 'xyz_%'

Comment: @user1614862 You can modify the quesy as per your need. That should not be the issue. See how in the edit post

Answer (score 1):

You can loop  through `user_tab_columns` and run delete in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Use proper exceptions in your final code.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

BEGIN
   FOR t IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME
               FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
              WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'CREATED_BY')
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
         'DELETE FROM ' || t.TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE CREATED_BY = ''xyz''');

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'DELETE FROM ' || t.TABLE_NAME || ' WHERE CREATED_BY = ''xyz''';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is superfluous here. A table cannot have two columns with the same name.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : Thanks. changed . I probably  thought of using all_tab_columns first.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
DELETE (SELECT *
        FROM tab1 
        INNER JOIN tab2
            ON tab1.id= tab2.id
        WHERE tab1.id >= any_value
            )
```

It will delete data from both tables.

Comment: not from just 2 tables, I have 1000 tables in my database, so I wanted to do it with some general query.

Comment: yea.. what I posted. I used two tables. You can join multiple tables and try deleting if that works.

Comment: that's what I cannot do for 1000 tables, right?

Comment: 1000 tables you didn't mention. You asked for simple query which can help. My assumption was on few tables not on 1000 tables.